# Haskell Date Parsing with Custom Separator

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to print out something like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import System.Environment
import Data.Time

main = do args <- getArgs
          let year = read $ args !! 0 
          let month = read $ args !! 1 
          let day = read $ args !! 2 
          let greg = fromGregorian year month day
          print $ showDateFormat $ toGregorian $ addDays 10 $ greg
          print $ showDateFormat $ toGregorian $ addDays 100 $ greg
          print $ showDateFormat $ toGregorian $ addDays 1000 $ greg
          print $ showDateFormat $ toGregorian $ addDays 10000 $ greg

showDateFormat :: (Integer,Int,Int) -> String
showDateFormat (y,m,d) = y ++ "/" ++ m ++ "/" ++ d ++ "\n"
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

This is the error I got:

[image]

Comment: How do you know that something is wrong?

Comment: You are trying to use the character `'/'` instead of the string `"/"` with `++`.

Comment: @chepner I have tried that before...

Comment: That's not your only problem. Haskell doesn't automatically convert an `Int` to a `String`; you have to do so explicitly. The reason being, there are lots of ways to do that: should the integer 51 be represented as "51" (decimal), "00110011" (binary), "30" (base 17), "LI" (roman numeral), "fifty-one" (English), etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell will not implicitly convert a value of one type to another; you have to do such things explicitly. In this case, you can use `show` to convert an `Int` or an `Integer` to a string containing its base-10 representation.

```
showDateFormat :: (Integer,Int,Int) -> String
showDateFormat (y,m,d) = show y ++ "/" ++ show m ++ "/" ++ show d ++ "\n"
```

The error message is literally telling you that it expects `y` to be a value of type `[Char]` (aka `String`), because `++` (receiving `"/" :: String` as one argument) expects a `String` as the other, but you have pass an `Integer` value for `y` instead.

(Note that `String` is the expected type because it is a *valid* type for `++`, while `Integer` is not. Otherwise, the type checker would use the left-hand argument to fix the type. `[1::Int] ++ "foo"`, for example, fails because `"foo"` does not have type `[Int]`, not because `[1]` does not have type `[Char]`.)